# Date is not converted exactly when read from excel

Tags: excel, openxml

I have an Excel spreadsheet that is being read.

The value in the spreadsheet is `7/24/2014 10:43:33 AM`

The cell value after being read using OpenXML is `41844.446908680555`.

When I do this calculation to convert to a date:

```
dte = DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(value));
```

I get `7/24/2014 10:43:32 AM`

Is this typical when converting date/time or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It seems that DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(value)); is truncating rather than rounding the fractional seconds.  Excel stores date/time as days and fractions of days since 1 Jan 1900 (with the intentional error of calling 1900 a leap year, supposedly for compatibility with Lotus 123 at the time).

Therefore, the number 41844.446908680555 translates to, given Excel's level of precision

- 7/24/2014 10:43:32.910

(actually: 7/24/2014 10:43:32.9099949030205)

Answer (score 0):

Just format the cells as Dates.  41844.446908680555 is Excel's way of serializing the date value.

Answer (score 0):

When Excel stores a date or time in stores it in a number format with the date January 1, 1900 = 1
so really when you’re storing a date with the date format you’re really just storing the numeric value of difference between the date and January 1, 1900

So for example 365  = jan-30-1900

And fractions of a number equal parts of the day so      .5 = half a day or 12 hours.

And for the fun of it right now = 41885.75   or sept-3-2014 at 6PM   or 41885.75 from jan 1 1900.

The reason why this is done is to now allowed dates to be used in mathematical functions. And it deals with a lot of problems that pop-up with dates such as leap year and also provides for easier ways to deal with time zones as well.